# Activerecord modified group_by with some aggregation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by

I've a following table: **Project**

[image]

I've to find Projects from year 2017 to previous 3 years. Then Group by the filtered projects based on `status`, `elim`, `industry` individually. Also, need some aggregation to find the total amount based on each year.

I've done the following and then got stuck.

```
results = {}
parameters = ['status', 'industry', 'elim']
@projects = Project.where("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", 3.year.ago, DateTime.new(2017).end_of_year)
parameters.each do |param|
  results[param] = @projects.group_by{|p| [p.created_at.year]}
end
```

Basically, I want the result be like:

```
results["status"] => [
                        "2017": ["Active": 1, "Successful": 1],
                        "2016": ["Inactive": 1],
                        "2015": ["Active": 1] 
                     ]

results["elim"] => [
                        "2017": ["Death": 2],
                        "2016": ["Flood": 1],
                        "2015": ["Flood": 1] 
                     ] 
results["amount"] => [
                         "2017": 32000.0,
                         "2016": 19000.0, 
                         "2015": 2000.0,
                     ]
```

How can I achieve that? Any clue?

Comment: `[  "2017": ["Death": 2],  "2016": ["Flood": 1],  "2015": ["Flood": 1]  ] ` is not a corret aray.

Comment: Why is that? If you check the table image above carefully you can see it is okay

Comment: Just paste above array in rails/ruby console & you'll come to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Salil's code, I modified it a bit, and got the expected answer.

```
parameters.each do |param|
  results[param] = @projects.group_by{|p| p.created_at.year}
  results[param].each do |key, values|
    results[param][key] = values.group_by{|p| p.status} # changed here
  end
end
```

Thanks, Salil. (+1) for your answer. But it's quite expensive I suppose. Any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
parameters.each do |param|
  results[param] = @projects.group_by{|p| p.created_at.year}
  results[param].each do |key, values|
    results[param][key] = values.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |v, counts| counts[v.send(param)] += 1 }
  end
end
```

result must be like following

```
results["status"] => {
                        "2017": {"Active": 1, "Successful": 1},
                        "2016": {"Inactive": 1},
                        "2015": {"Active": 1} 
                     }
```

Comment: actually, parameters are not `status`, they are column names by which I need to group_by

Comment: so, basically if I need `results["elim"]` then I need to run that for loop again?

Comment: Can you please post the results which you are getting right now ?

Comment: Please check my answer again

Comment: Not getting the expected output :(, okay, can you tell me is it possible without two for each loop?

Comment: what you getting ? what is you expecting ?

Comment: Please not the change `{ |v, counts| counts[v.send(param)] += 1 }` 7 check again